# Streaming numbers from a file

Tags: c++, stream, numbers

I was hoping there was someone who could help me with the problem I am having here. My program is below, and the problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to write the process() function to take a .txt file with a bunch of random numbers, read the numbers, and output only the positive ones to a separate file. I have been stuck on this for days now and I don't know where else to turn. If anyone could provide some help of any kind I would be very appreciative, thank you.

```
/*  
    10/29/13
    Problem: Write a program which reads a stream of numbers from a file, and writes only the positive ones to a second file. The user enters the names of the input and output files. Use a function named process which is passed the two opened streams, and reads the numbers one at a time, writing only the positive ones to the output.

*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void process(ifstream & in, ofstream & out);

int main(){
    char inName[200], outName[200];

    cout << "Enter name including path for the input file: ";
    cin.getline(inName, 200);
    cout << "Enter name and path for output file: ";
    cin.getline(outName, 200);

    ifstream in(inName);
    in.open(inName);
    if(!in.is_open()){ //if NOT in is open, something went wrong
        cout << "ERROR: failed to open " << inName << " for input" << endl;
        exit(-1);       // stop the program since there is a problem
    }
    ofstream out(outName);
    out.open(outName);
    if(!out.is_open()){ // same error checking as above.
        cout << "ERROR: failed to open " << outName << " for outpt" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    process(in, out); //call function and send filename

    in.close();
    out.close();

    return 0;
}


void process(ifstream & in, ofstream & out){
        char c;
    while (in >> noskipws >> c){ 
        if(c > 0){
            out << c;
        }
    }

    //This is what the function should be doing:
    //check if files are open
    // if false , exit
    // getline data until end of file
    // Find which numbers in the input file are positive
    //print to out file
    //exit


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `char` for the extraction. What if the value to be extracted is greater than 1 byte? Also, `std::noskipws` turns *off* the skipping of whitespace, effectively making it difficult to extract a whitespace separated list of numbers. Use only `std::noskipws` if a whitespace character is valid character to extract, otherwise let the file stream do its job.

If you know the Standard library well, you can use generic algorithms like `std::remove_copy_if` that take iterators like the ones below:

```
void process(std::ifstream& in, std::ofstream& out)
{
    std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
                        std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                        std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, " "),
                                            [] (int x) { return x % 2 != 0; });
}
```

This requires use of C++11. Add the `-std=c++11` option to your program or upgrade your compiler.

If you can't use these methods, then at least use `int` during the extraction:

```
int i;

while (in >> i)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        out << i;
}
```

You said in your comments that you need to use `getline`. This is wrong. I'm assuming here that you have multiple lines of space-separated integers. If this is the case, `getline` is unneeded.

Comment: Ok thank you for that. When i run the program I type in the name of the input file, the name of the desired output file. Then it finishes. I go to look at the output file and it has nothing in it at all. So im still not sure what's wrong with the program. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2917900 Are you getting any errors? Let me search for further problems.

Comment: Im using Visual studio 2012. I'm not getting any errors. I'm running the program I have above, with your correction. I type the input file name I made with some random positive and negative numbers in that file, then the desired output file name. Then there is nothing in that output file (when there should be the positive numbers from the input file).

Comment: @user2917900 I think I see the problem. It's in your `main` clause: You did `file.open()` even though the files were *already open* with the paths you supplied through the constructor. Because of that, `failbit` is set in the stream and subsequent I/O operations do nothing. Please remove the `in.open()` and `out.open()` from your code.

Comment: That did it! Thank's a lot. Now i just need to figure out how to keep the space between the integers. The program took out the white space between them, then send them to the output file. So i just get a big list of numbers with no spaces.

Comment: @user2917900 Are you using the first version of my code or the second? If it's the first, I already made an edit to my code that puts a space between each number. If it's the second, do `out << i << " "`.